# Is there a way to have my formulas reference a single cell value so that I can change multiple formulas with the one cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I have 3 formulas

```
=LEFT(Tickets!C14,(FIND(".",Tickets!C14,1)-1))

=Tickets!A14

=Tickets!E14
```

I am using them to pull information from a table, and create an email for me. If I could alter one cell, and have it change the reference location, I would have what I want/need. (i.e. I need to change "14" to whatever row I am referencing, but I would prefer not to use Find/Replace everytime)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX:

The basic is that you would replace any reference with `INDEX(column,CellRefofTheRow)`

So

```
=Tickets!A14
```

Becomes:

```
=INDEX(Tickets!A:A,A1)
```

Where `A1` would hold the row number desired like `14`

Comment: Holy crap it works! Thanks a bunch! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @JacobBodie if it worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I have the simpler two of the three functions working, however, I can not seem to get the first one working. Any ideas?

=LEFT(=INDEX(Tickets!C:C,B2),(FIND(".",(=INDEX(Tickets!C:C,B2),1)-1))

thats what I have down, but I'm not sure where i've got an error..

Comment: `=LEFT(INDEX(Tickets!C:C,B2),(FIND(".",INDEX(Tickets!C:C,B2),1)-1))`

Comment: And just like that, it works, amazing, thanks Scott!